# Variance of stochastic integral of brownian motion

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

How do i compute this integral?

$ Var [\int_0^T W(t)dW(t)] $

I know the following $E [\int_0^T W(t)dW(t)]$ is 0 but i'm not sure how to apporch the above

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let

$$X := \int_0^T W(t) \, dW(t)$$

By definition,

$$\text{var}X = \mathbb{E}((X-\mathbb{E}X)^2)$$

You already figured out that $\mathbb{E}X=0$, i.e.

$$\text{var} X = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^T W(t) \, dW(t) \right)^2 \right]$$

**Hint** Apply Itô's isometry.

Comment: so the result if $\frac{1}{2} t^2$?

Comment: I guess you mean $\frac{T^2}{2}$ - and yes, that's correct.

Comment: Could someone explain why the result is $\frac{T^2}{2}$? I'm new to Ito integrals and am having some difficulty understanding the basics.

Comment: @Jess But you know Itô's isometry, right? So what do you obtain if you apply it?

Answer (score 2):

I belive we should mention using Fubini's theorem to swap integral and expectation signs:
$\mathbb{E}\left[\int^T_0 W_t^2 dt\right]=\int^T_0\mathbb{E}[W^2_t]dt=\frac{T^2}{2}$

Comment: What is the expectation of that function squared? I'm having trouble calculating it

Comment: This would be the variance of Brownian motion: given $W_t \sim N(0,t)$ we have $\mathbb{E}[W^2_t] =t $

Answer (score 0):

apply Ito Isometry and you will get t.dt after taking expectation of $W^2$ (which is t) and $dW^2$ which will be $dt$.  $W$ and $dW$ are independent so you take expectation individually.
So integral of $t.dt$ from $0$ to $T$ which is $\frac{T^2}{2}$